# Using pip install at work behind proxy - EnvironmentError

Tags: python, proxy, pip

I am trying to install some packages at work using pip install, there is a proxy so I cannot do it the conventional way or I get an error.

I am trying to use

```
pip install --proxy=https://[username:password@]proxyserver:port upgrade pip wheel setuptools
```

However the above gives me an error of "Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Failed to parse: ]proxyserver:port"

I also tried to use

```
pip install --proxy="user:password@server:port" upgrade pip wheel setuptools
```

But it gives me an error of below

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Failed to
>   parse: server:port

Both times it does start the process, it says Collecting upgrade but then fails.

Comment: Are you missing https:// before server?

Comment: I did use https:// in the first try but same error.

Comment: But did you use it without the brackets?

Comment: Yes sir but it is still giving me the below error:

**Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Failed to parse: proxyserver:port**

Comment: Any special characters? Those would need to be encoded.

Comment: I am not really sure, would the "@" be a special character?

Comment: pip should respect `netrc` for storing credentials...  I don't have/use Windows but this might help https://superuser.com/q/620143

Comment: Hi. Did my answer below help you?

Answer (score 2):

I setup a proxy server on my machine so I could test this out

If my password contains a special character like # or @ then it complains with the error that you are seeing (see my screenshot). If I encode the special character # > %23 then I get no error.

[image: pip]